# Completely remove console logging from .NET Core 2.0 Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, logging, asp.net-core, serilog

I did this:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
{
    return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5000")
        .ConfigureLogging(ConfigureLogging)
        .Build();
}

private static void ConfigureLogging(WebHostBuilderContext hostingContext, ILoggingBuilder logging)
{   
    logging.ClearProviders();
}
```

And my `appsettings.json`:

```
{

}
```

But still.. I get exceptions logged to `Console` - can somebody explain why? Pointers?

[image: Exception is still logged to Console]

Comment: … where and how are you using that `ConfigureLogging`? Just having a method like that will not just disable logging…

Comment: It is invoked when building the web host, updated answer.

Comment: It should work like that. You have the question tagged with “serilog”, do you use Serilog? Do you have any other logging-related setup elsewhere?

Comment: I would like to use `Serilog` but I am not currently, step 1 is to remove all logging from the framework/CLR/Kestrel - then I will add ONLY serilog Json logging.

Comment: Can you share a bit more about your application? And maybe show the logs that are printed to the console (to confirm that these are actual log entries)? I cannot replicate your problem right now.

Comment: I cannot expose more than I already have since I am bound by legal obligations. But i have updated my answer with the output after forcing an exception be thrown.

Comment: Can you run the application actually from the command line isntead of within Visual Studio? – Also, if you cannot share more and cannot reproduce the problem in a [mcve], then I’m afraid we cannot help you.

Answer (score 3):

You can configure the logging while creating the webhost like this

```
 private static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureLogging(config => {
                    config.ClearProviders();
                })
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

The config.ClearProviders() will remove all logging service and only produce minimal information

Answer (score 0):

The framework has a default `ILoggerFactory` that it will use if none is registered.

When you add `UseSerilog()`, this will replace the default factory, and the default console logging will go away.

Comment: You mean `AddSerilog` probably? But even if I do this: `logging.AddSerilog(logger, true); logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.None);`, I still get exceptions in my console.

Comment: The framework only has a single logger factory that is created by the web host where logging providers are attached to. OP’s way of calling `loggerBuilder.ClearProviders()` in the web host builder should properly clear all default providers making all logs go into the void. Depending on what `UseSerilog()` you are referring to, this should *not* clear existing providers.

Comment: @Marcus no; https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore has superseded the older compat lib, and now provides `UseSerilog()` rather than `AddSerilog()` - the README over there should help